# which one is correct to use in the below sentence? (to be or is going to be)

Tags: sentence-structure

I was reading [this article](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/community-built-for-foreigners-in-dubai-to-be-torn-down/6309375.html) in VOA Learning English but its title structure was a little odd to me.

> Community Built for Foreigners in Dubai **to Be Torn Down**

Can i write below sentence as an alternative:

Community Built for Foreigners in Dubai **is going to** be torn down

Comment: This is **headlinese**, so you should look up that term.  Headlines are not usually written like complete sentences.

Comment: And yes, your rewrite is a good way of understanding the omitted words.